# How to list all products in Platform of Trust?

Tags: product, platform, platform-of-trust

I'm trying to find an example how to list all data products in Platform of Trust marketplace preferably with a REST API. Is there public API documentation with code examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Platform of Trust publishes documentation on the APIs and you can get the list of all available data products via the Product API.

Currently that is via a `GET` request to their `/products/v1/` -endpoint. Host depends on the environment you want to interact with (e.g. `https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net` for the sandbox environment).

Since this answer is likely going to get eventually out of date, here's a link to that documentation https://docs.oftrust.net/#product-api